# With TfLite, the last EfficientDet op (TFLite_Detection_PostProcess) is not supported on the GPU

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, object-detection, tensorflow-lite, automl

I'm running the TfLite model analyzer on Google Brain's AutoML [EfficientDet](https://github.com/google/automl/tree/master/efficientdet/tf2) model like so:

```
model_path = "/content/efficientdet.tflite"
tf.lite.experimental.Analyzer.analyze(model_path=model_path, gpu_compatibility=True)
```

The [analyzer output](https://gist.github.com/saad-palapa/a3827a9ed6271db217a4b59c2498e602#file-gistfile1-txt-L491) shows that the last layer is not a supported TfLite GPU operation:

```
GPU COMPATIBILITY WARNING: Not supported custom op TFLite_Detection_PostProcess
GPU COMPATIBILITY WARNING: Subgraph#0 has GPU delegate compatibility issues at nodes 482 with TFLite runtime version 2.8.2
```

The [TFLite_Detection_PostProcess](https://github.com/google/automl/blob/master/efficientdet/tf2/postprocess.py#L29) operator is not supported on the GPU. This is causing [CPU/GPU synchronization issues](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/gpu#troubleshooting_gpu_support) and it is increasing the latency.

What do I need to do to get the op running on the GPU in Tensorflow Lite?

I'm open to re-compiling the TfLite binary or modifying the neural network.

Answer (score -1):

Suggested workaround will be to use 2.11 TFLite Runtime and efficientdet model from Tensorflow hub which are regularly tested and maintained.

Attached [gist](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/mohantym/0a1a07ea8ea992654b628ba25cab67e5/stack_73919871.ipynb) for reference.

Comment: I don't think your solution works. It's showing this in the gist:

`GPU COMPATIBILITY WARNING: Not supported custom op TFLite_Detection_PostProcess`

Comment: Yeah, saw that for node 266. I think we can disable quantization for the layers having gpu compatibility through [tfl.quantization_debugger](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/quantization_debugger)/[tfmot](https://www.tensorflow.org/model_optimization/api_docs/python/tfmot) api . will come with a updated gist later. Thank you!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).